# modify strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas

I have the following dataframe called df

```
    country ticker   
01  ST      ENRO.ST
02  ST      ERICb.ST
03  ST      BTSb.ST
04  US      MSFT
05  HK      0070.HK
06  ST      SAABb.ST
07  ST      SaA.ST
```

I want to do the following,

if the country == 'ST', select the string in the ticker row.

check if there are any lowercase characters.

If there is a lowercase character, add a hyphen before it and make the letter uppercase, like this.

```
    country ticker   
01  ST      ENRO.ST
02  ST      ERIC-B.ST
03  ST      BTS-B.ST
04  US      MSFT
05  HK      0070.HK
06  ST      SAAB-B.ST
07  ST      S-AA.ST
```

I would do the following if it was just one string,

```
teststr = [char for char in "ERICb.ST"]:
for i,v in enumerate(teststr):
    if teststr[i].islower():
        mod = i

teststr[mod] = teststr[mod].upper()

teststr.insert(mod,'-')
teststr = ''.join(teststr)
```

but i dont know how to apply it to every row if it meets that condition.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple lowercase letters which have to be replaced?

Comment: no, there can only be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we split the strings up based on the lowercase letters, then we join them back with `-` as delimiter on the first two parts and uppercase the strings, then we add the last part. Finally we use `Series.where` to only modify the rows where `country == ST`:

```
s1 = df['ticker'].str.split('([a-z])')
s2 = s1.str[:2].str.join('-').str.upper() + s1.str[2:].str.join('')
df['ticker'] = s2.where(df['country'].eq('ST'), df['ticker'])

  country     ticker
0      ST    ENRO.ST
1      ST  ERIC-B.ST
2      ST   BTS-B.ST
3      US       MSFT
4      HK    0070.HK
5      ST  SAAB-B.ST
6      ST    S-AA.ST
```

Comment: hey sorry, what about only selecting the rows with 'ST' in the country, because there could be rows with lower case characters if there when its not ST and i dont want to touch those, i mentioned it in the first part of the question

Answer (score 0):

you may use replace function with `str.replace`

```
repl = lambda x: '-'+x.group(0).upper()

df.loc[df.country.eq('ST'), 'ticker'] = (df.loc[df.country.eq('ST'), 'ticker']
                                           .str.replace('([a-z])', repl))

Out[58]:
  country     ticker
1      ST    ENRO.ST
2      ST  ERIC-B.ST
3      ST   BTS-B.ST
4      US       MSFT
5      HK    0070.HK
6      ST  SAAB-B.ST
7      ST    S-AA.ST
```

**Note**: as you said there is only a single lowercase char in each string so I use the pattern `[a-z]`